# What does this "t" do?

Tags: sql, postgresql, table-alias

I'm having trouble understanding the following example from the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html):

```
-- set returning function WITH ORDINALITY
SELECT * FROM pg_ls_dir('.') WITH ORDINALITY AS t(ls,n);
       ls        | n
-----------------+----
 pg_serial       |  1
 pg_twophase     |  2
 postmaster.opts |  3
 pg_notify       |  4
...
```

The things inside the parentheses of the `t(...)` become the column names, but what is the `t` itself? I'm asking here because the docs don't explain it, and a single-letter function is ungoogleable. In fact, the docs don't even explain what is supposed to come after `AS`; the only thing we get is this one example.

It seems I can replace `t` by any other identifier, and it still works.

Comment: its alias for a set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is:

> ```
> function_call [WITH ORDINALITY] [[AS] table_alias [(column_alias [, ... ])]]
> ```
>
> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS

`t` is an arbitrary *table alias*; you can give it any valid name you want.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I wasn't looking at the canonical part of the docs after all.

Answer (score 1):

it's alias for a set, to be able to reference it in column list, eg:

```
SELECT t.*,pg_database .datname 
FROM pg_ls_dir('.') WITH ORDINALITY AS t(ls,n) 
join pg_database on true where datname = 'postgres'
          ls          | n  | datname
----------------------+----+----------
 pg_dynshmem          |  1 | postgres
 postmaster.pid       |  2 | postgres
 PG_VERSION           |  3 | postgres
 base                 |  4 | postgres
```